# I Get the Image URL's from S3 bucket using Angularjs but how to make that Image to be download from client side

Tags: angularjs, amazon-s3

I will get all the s3 bucket object URL in the Console.
How to download that object from client side using Angularjs

```
app.controller('Sample', function($scope) {

   AWS.config.update({
       accessKeyId: '',
       secretAccessKey: ''
   });

   AWS.config.region = "us-east-1";
   $scope.s3Url = '';

   var bucket = new AWS.S3({
      params: {
         Bucket: 'mybucketname',
         Prefix: 'UPLOADS'
      }
   });

   bucket.listObjects(function(err, data) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
     } else {
        console.log(data.Contents[1]);
        $scope.imgData = $scope.s3Url + data.Contents[1].Key;
        console.log($scope.imgData);
     }
   });

});
```

Comment: Specifically https://stackoverflow.com/a/30832210/5535245 Tested to be working properly in Chrome, FireFox and IE10.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you. This works on chrome and firefox but not sure on other browser.

```
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 's3_url_image.png';
link.download = 'download_filename.png';
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```